# Compile error in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am a newbie in OCaml and i dont know how to compile this :

I have this labyrinthe.mli :

```
type is                 = bool
type ouverte            = bool

type case               = (is)
type porte              = (ouverte * case * case)
type lab                = (case * porte * porte * porte * porte)

val create_case         : is -> case
val create_porte        : ouverte -> case -> case -> porte
val create_lab          : case -> porte -> porte -> porte -> porte -> lab
```

and this main.ml :

```
let c1          = Labyrinthe.create_case false
let c2          = Labyrinthe.create_case false
let c3          = Labyrinthe.create_case false
let c4          = Labyrinthe.create_case false
let case        = Labyrinthe.create_case true

let p1          = Labyrinthe.create_porte false case c1
let p2          = Labyrinthe.create_porte false case c2
let p3          = Labyrinthe.create_porte false case c3
let p4          = Labyrinthe.create_porte false case c4

let lab         = Labyrinthe.create_lab case p1 p2 p3 p4
```

I compile the two files like that : ocamlopt labrinthe.mli main.ml but it doesn't work.

I have the following message error : File "main.ml", line 1:
Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:
         Labyrinthe referenced from main.cmx

I've tried everything i've found on internet but nothing worked :(
Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Do you want to create an executable or an object file?

Comment: I want to create an executable but i would like to know how to make an object file too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not supply an implementation for the labyrinthe interface. You can't create an executable without an implementation. After all, what code should execute when you call, for example, `create_case` in main?

If you want separate compilation, you can create an object file using the `-c` flag. You can then link that object file with the object file containing labyrinthe's implementation to create the executable.